# how to synchronize a shiny progress bar with a llply progress bar

Tags: r, shiny, plyr

I would like to find a way to show a llply progress bar inside the shiny UI.
please have a look to the code bellow. Do you have any idea ?

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
function_I_cant_edit <- function(){plyr::llply(LETTERS ,.fun=function(x){Sys.sleep(0.2)},.progress = "text")}

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {


  observeEvent(input$go, {

    progress <- shiny::Progress$new(session, min=1, max=15)
    on.exit(progress$close())
    progress$set(message = 'Calculation in progress')
    function_I_cant_edit()

    for (i in 1:15) {
      progress$set(value = i)
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
    }

  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(cars)
  })
})

ui <- basicPage(
  actionButton("go","PUSH ME"),
  plotOutput("plot")

)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

An idea is to use progress="tk" inside the llply, but is there a sexiest way ?

Another idea will be to show the console output in the shiny app... but I didn't manage this.

Regards

EDIT :

the llpy function use progress_tk() or progress_text() or progress_time()

So I created a progress_shiny() function

```
    progress_shiny <-function (title = "plyr progress", label = "Working...", ...) 
{
  n <- 0
  tk <- NULL
  list(init = function(x) {
    tk    <<- shiny::Progress$new(session,min=1, max=15)

    tk$set(message = 'Calculation in progress')
  }, step = function() {
    n <<- n + 1
    tk$set(value = n)
  }, term = function() print("fin"))
}
```

And I tried :

```
server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  # session <<- session
  observeEvent(input$go, {


    # function_I_cant_edit()
    llply(LETTERS ,.fun=function(x){Sys.sleep(0.2)},.progress = "shiny")


  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(cars)
  })
})

ui <- basicPage(
  actionButton("go","PUSH ME"),
  plotOutput("plot")

)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But the error message is 'Error in public_bind_env$initialize(...) : objet 'session' introuvable' ...

I think i m on the way to find something ;)

Comment: The progress bar from `plyr` is just text printed to the console, which can be captured with `capture.output`, but I don't think you'll be able to get the progress bar from `plyr` to the Shiny UI.

Comment: Thks, I know that, but the capture.output will not be in real time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom progress handler that takes a `progress` object from shiny, e.g.

```
progress_shiny <-function (progress, step = 1){
  list(
    init = function(n){},
    step = function() {
      progress$set( progress$getValue() + step )
    }, 
    term = function(){}
  )
}
```

And use it something like this in your server code.

```
observeEvent(input$go, {
  progress <- shiny::Progress$new(session, min=0, max=50)
  on.exit(progress$close())

  # use the main progress outside of llply 
  progress$set( value = 1)
  Sys.sleep( 1 )
  progress$set( value = 20 )

  # then pass it along so that llply steps 
  # contribute to the main progress
  llply(LETTERS ,.fun=function(x){
    Sys.sleep(0.2)
  }, .progress = progress_shiny(progress))

})
```

This way the progress bar inside `llply` contributes to the main progress bar

Answer (score 0):

Following the [code from the plyr package](https://rdrr.io/github/hadley/plyr/src/R/progress.r) you can also put the initialization and termination of the progress dialogue into the function as well. That, together with some sensible defaults, makes for a rather clean call.

```
progress_shiny <- function(session, min=0, value=min, step=1, message="Working...") {
  p<-NULL
  list(
    init = function(max) {
      p<<-shiny::Progress$new(session, min=min, max=max)
      p$set(value=value, message=message)
    },
    step = function() {
      p$inc(step)
    },
    term = function(){
      p$close()  
    }
  )
}
```

Usage becomes much shorter:

```
observeEvent(input$go, {
  # no additional setup needed
  llply(LETTERS ,.fun=function(x){
    Sys.sleep(0.2)
  }, .progress = progress_shiny(session))
})
```